# XPages and chained partial refresh

Tags: xpages, refresh, partial

I would like to perform a partial refresh on a second panel after the first partial refresh has completed. This is my code from the source:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox3" value="#{document1.Company}">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Select a Company" itemValue="Select a Company">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItems>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db = sessionScope.serverPath + "!!" + sessionScope.dbName; @Trim(@Unique(@DbColumn(db, "vwTblCompany",1)));}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlLocation">
</xp:eventHandler>
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true" refreshId="pnlLocation">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("comboBox4").setValue("Select a Location");}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
<xp:eventHandler>
<xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[function() {
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:pnlApprovalInfo}");
}]]></xp:this.onComplete>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

The error I get when I click on the keyword field is:

An error occurred while updating some of the page.   Cannot read property 'call' of null.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I figured out how to do it:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox3" value="#{document1.Company}">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Select a Company" itemValue="Select a Company">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItems>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db = sessionScope.serverPath + "!!" + sessionScope.dbName; @Trim(@Unique(@DbColumn(db, "vwTblCompany",1)));}]]>  
</xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlLocation">
<xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:pnlApprovalInfo}")]]></xp:this.onComplete>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: I recommend using a setTimeout in the onComplete code so that the prior XSP process is completed before the new one begins: eg: setTimeout(function(){XPS.partialRefreshGet(...)}, 1);

Comment: Thanks Henry. Appreciate the advice.